# Jquery appending extra # to DOM objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the following error in IE9

SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ##chart1 
jquery-2.0.3.min.js, line 4 character 14519

I am not sure why given the code which is shown below. I clearly do not add it to the HTML string and only have 1 when i reference it in the jqplot call. So why is it shooting out this error?

```
function createGraph() {
    var HTMLstring = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<HTML>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<HEAD>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<TITLE> Frequency Graph</TITLE>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->\n';
    HTMLstring += '<script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>\n';
    HTMLstring += '</HEAD>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<BODY>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<div><span>Moused Over: </span><span id="infomouseover">Nothing</span></div>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<div><span>Clicked: </span><span id="infoclicked">Nothing</span></div>\n';
    HTMLstring += '<div id="chart1" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px; width:300px; height:300px;"></div>\n';
    HTMLstring += '</BODY>\n';
    HTMLstring += '</HTML>';
    newwindow = window.open();
    newdocument = newwindow.document;
    newdocument.write(HTMLstring);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        freqchart = $.jqplot('#chart1', [
            [
                [2, 1],
                [4, 2],
                [6, 3],
                [3, 4]
            ],
            [
                [5, 1],
                [1, 2],
                [3, 3],
                [4, 4]
            ],
            [
                [4, 1],
                [7, 2],
                [1, 3],
                [2, 4]
            ]
        ], {
            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                pointLabels: {
                    show: true,
                    location: 'e',
                    edgeTolerance: -15
                },
                shadowAngle: 135,
                rendererOptions: {
                    barDirection: 'horizontal'
                }
            },
            axes: {
                yaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                }
            }
        });

        $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataHighlight',
            function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
                $('#infomouseover').html('series: ' + seriesIndex + ', point: ' + pointIndex + ', data: ' + data + ', pageX: ' + ev.pageX + ', pageY: ' + ev.pageY);
            }
        );

        $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick',
            function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
                $('#infoclicked').html('series: ' + seriesIndex + ', point: ' + pointIndex + ', data: ' + data + ', pageX: ' + ev.pageX + ', pageY: ' + ev.pageY);
            }
        );

        $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataUnhighlight',
            function (ev) {
                $('#infomouseover').html('Nothing');
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`jqPlot()` doesn't require a CSS style selector to find an Id. It handles that itself, thus currently it looks for `#chart1` with an appended `#` twice.

```
<script>
    //This will look for #chart1
    $.jqplot('chart1', [data], options );
</script>
```

[jsplot Docs](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html)

> "Create the actual plot by calling the `$.jqplot()` plugin with the **id** of your target"

Answer (score 1):

jqplot takes the element id as a parameter not an id selector so `$.jqplot('#chart1',` should be `$.jqplot('chart1',` etc.

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html